# Can't find no employees in each department

Tags: sql, oracle

DEPARTMENT Table

```
DEPARTMENT_ID
| 1       |
| 2       |
```

EMPLOYEES Table

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID
ANDY        | 1
```

Output

```
DEPARTMENT_ID|
2
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM DEPARTMENTS
where department_id!= all ( SELECT department_id
               FROM employees
           );
```

The code doesn't show `2`,and the output is blank.

Like this:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.department_id 
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN employees e ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE e.department_id IS NULL
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbca0f00/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the *number* of each employee in each department, you should use a left join aggregation:

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS cnt
FROM DEPARTMENT d
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES e
    ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

The above count expression counts the `EMPLOYEE_ID` column in the employee table.  It is important to note that should a department have no employees, then `COUNT` would return zero, since `NULL` is not counted.